# Fix following id's or update sequence when a row is deleted from a table - PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-insert, sql-delete

I have a doubt in deleting a row in the user table and to add new data in the same table but instead of occupying the row of place off, create a new row, in fact the implementation is in the user sequence that increments 1 each since you add a new data into the table of users and perhaps to solve this doubt, it will be necessary to use function or triggers

create table users and primary key

```
/* table user*/
create table users (id_user number(10) not null, 
                    name_user varchar(30) not null);

/* primary key */
alter table users add constraint user_pk primary key (id_user);

/* create sequence */
create sequence seq_user increment by 1 start with 1;

/* insert two user date */
insert into users(id_user, name_user) values(seq_user.NEXTVAL, 'Renata Souza');
insert into users(id_user, name_user) values(seq_user.NEXTVAL, 'Rihanna Smith');
```

select all users

```
select  * from users;
```

[image]

the doubt is, if I `delete` the `id_user = 2` like

```
/* delete user with id = 2 */
delete from users where id_user = 2;

/*select users*/
select  * from users;
```

[image]

and if I `insert` more two dates for users

```
insert into users(id_user, name_user) values(seq_user.NEXTVAL, 'Sara Carbonero');
insert into users(id_user, name_user) values(seq_user.NEXTVAL, 'Patricia Guedes');

/*select users*/
select  * from users;
```

[image]

in fact, the `sequence_user` should `start by id_user = 2` but `starts at 3`, is there any `function` or `triggers` able to `update` the `sequence_user` if the row is deleted

now in PL/SQL

```
/* Create user */
    PROCEDURE create_user(p_name   IN VARCHAR2,
                          p_error  OUT NUMBER,
                          p_msg_error OUT VARCHAR2)
      IS
      BEGIN
        p_error := 0;
        INSERT INTO users (id_user, name_user) VALUES(seq_user.NEXTVAL, p_name)
    COMMIT;
      EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        p_error     := 1;
        p_msg_error := 'Error!'||SQLERRM;
      END create_user;
```

Now I want to delete this user

```
PROCEDURE delete_user(
    p_id_user IN NUMBER,
    p_error OUT NUMBER,
    p_msg_error OUT VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
  p_error := 0;
  DELETE FROM users  WHERE users.id_user = p_id_user;
  COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  p_error     := 1;
  p_msg_error := 'Error!'||SQLERRM;
END delete_user;
```

Comment: Did u used a sequence for ID column? if you did, it makes it. You should maybe use selext max(id)+1 from users , something like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is never, absolutely never, a guarantee that an oracle sequence will give you an uninterupted sequence of numbers. If that is what you want then you will need to do your own

```
SELECT MAX(id)+1 ...
```

amended Create User procedure

```
/* Create user */
    PROCEDURE create_user(p_name   IN VARCHAR2,
                          p_error  OUT NUMBER,
                          p_msg_error OUT VARCHAR2)
      IS
        l_nextUser NUMBER;
      BEGIN
        p_error := 0;
        SELECT MAX(id_user)+1
          INTO l_nextUser
          FROM users;

        INSERT INTO users (id_user, name_user) VALUES(l_nextUser, p_name)
    COMMIT;
      EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        p_error     := 1;
        p_msg_error := 'Error!'||SQLERRM;
      END create_user;
```

Comment: ok,  but I need to use in `procedure`, I don´t explain better but the logic  is `create procedure` to `insert` the date in table and other to `delete` the dates and when I insert again to show new date with fix id

Comment: that's fine, i your procedure have a SELECT MAX statement, and use the output from this for you INSERT

Comment: I have my `procedure` in this [link](http://pastebin.com/FSajdsap), you can see and tell where I put `select max(id_user)+1` , if I used the sequence for increment de colum and row, I guess

Comment: sorry, my companies security does not allow me to view that site

Comment: not problem, I have updated the code by adding the `procedures` in `PL SQL`